# how can I read content of image data from sql server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, arcgis

I have a `ArcSDE SQL server database`. according to [arcSDE schema](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/system_1203016261.htm) CodedValues for domains in geodatabase stored in `GDB_CODEDDOMAINS table` in `IMAGE format`. how can I convert this image data type of coded values to string that can be human understandable. In other word I want to convert this data type to string and extract each code value of domain in separate string variable.
please give me idea to do this work.

If the question is unclear pleas tell me to explain more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of an `IMAGE` type column come back to C# as a `byte[]`. You can basically do anything with it. My first guess would be to try to convert it to a `string` using

```
string content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
```

Comment: thank for your answer but my problem is when i use this code, this result back to me `"\0\0\0\b\01\0�����\02\0��������\03\0����\04\0������ �� �� ����\05\0������ �� �� ����\0"`i think this is because of persian font that the code value written by it. can i solve this problem?

Comment: You might have to play with the encoding a bit. Another possible problem might be that the byte array really is not supposed to be human readable, but contains non-printable characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv

Comment: tanks but i am going to convert image to string not byte to image